# SSH Connectivity Issue

Tags: 20.04, gnome, ssh, openssh, sshd

Why does the ssh client stop connecting to servers either right after reboot or few minutes after reboot?

[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hGDw.png)

I found this in both **ubuntu 20** as well as **ubuntu 22**. My server is working fine as i can connect to to server using other devices. The ssh deamon on he client is also working fine!! as i can ssh into the client machine..

**sudo systemctl status ssh**

shows that every thing is fine and is working properly

I have tried everything (install openssh-*, uninstall and reinstall openssh-*, uninstall and reinstall openssh-client, uninstall openssh-* and install openssh-server, uninstall openssh-* and install openssh-client). It may get fixed by one of these methods, but alas when i start my pc the next day the issue comes back

Comment: Please clarify your Ubuntu details.. 20 & 22 are *specialist* Iot/cloud server *flavors* of 20.04 & 22.04, neither of which had GNOME available.  You mention those products in your question (20 & 22 have no `apt` commands being *snap* only) but have tagged a *year.month* product (20.04) which is *deb* based and can thus use *deb* and *snap* packages  (22.04 was released in 2022-April; yet the 22 *flavor* wasn't released until [July](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-core-22-is-now-available/28928) being the *specialist* smaller *flavor*.

Comment: Please enclose output of these commands got in situation when SSH connection fails: `sudo netstat -lntp | grep "22"` and `ip addr` and `sudo ps -ef | grep -C3 ssh` and `iptables-save`. Compare these results with the other results got when the SSH state is OK.